# kivy language cumbersomeness and rationale behind it

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, kivy

Kivy has this [kv language](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) to define the UI , the definition file can become quite complex , There is a kv designer package on github which automates the generation of kv files but is quite buggy and unreliable. So the question is why does kivy want the programmer to manually write those UI definitions like even hardcode the  positions and dimensions of UI widgets. Most other libraries like QT, VB etc have a UI designer as the core feature but Kivy did not start with it and expects programmers to hardcode it , I find it pretty cumbersome although I feel I am missing something. Or is it that it is only I who find a steep learning curve for kv language and I don't know about some tools which help in writing kv files.

Comment: Actually, most other frameworks _didn't_ have a UI designer as a core feature in version 1.0, but grew one later. IIRC, QtDesigner 1.0 was a separate program that came out around the same time as Qt 2.1 or 2.2 (one of many competing programs), and only because part of the core Qt system in Qt 4. In Gtk+ and Wx, the UI designer is still not used in most programs (and in many tutorials) even though it's pretty stable.

Comment: Also, not many people are still using Dreamweaver, FrontPage, and other similar GUI designers for HTML GUIs. And Flex was created because many people didn't like being forced to use a GUI UI designer for Flash apps, to the point where Macromedia was worried that its "Flash on the desktop" idea would fail if they didn't come up with something more HTML-like. The idea that a GUI designer is necessary to build GUIs feels very late-90s to me…

Comment: @abarnert agreed but how to maintain complex UIs as the file size would increase and would be difficult to manage \\maintain them , also why to hardcode dimensions and positional values?

Comment: How do people maintain complex HTML or Gtk+ UIs? Typically, the answer is to move toward more procedural generation rather than descriptive. You may not think that's a good solution (and the Cocoa team at Apple would probably agree with you), but it's the solution that many GUI frameworks seem to lean toward.

Comment: For the "also": How would using a graphical designer change the fact that they use hardcoded dimensions? Qt and Gtk+ use relative layouts even though Qt is (since 4.0) built around a designer while Gtk+ is not; VB and wx use pixel-based layouts, even though VB is built around a designer and wx is not.

Comment: also are there any tools to debug, edit kv files, like showing the availaible events, properties etc for  a widget , autocompletion etc?

Comment: Anyway, you've got three difference questions here; which do you want answered: (1) are there any QtDesigner-like tools for Kivy, (2) why wasn't Kivy designed around an interface builder, (3) why wasn't Kivy designed around relative layouts.

Comment: If you're asking #1, that's really a library-shopping question, and StackOverflow is not a good place for those. When I googled "Kivy designer" and "Kivy interface builder", I saw at least two different projects on the first page (one called `KivyDesigner`). There may be others. Some of them may suck. Probably none of them are from Kivy themselves. Pretty much like the state of Qt in its 1.x days.

Comment: @abarnert yes all three questions are related to each other , the answer to which justifies the other question(s).

Comment: and I know there are not much useful tools already, so my question is more about answering 2 and 3

Comment: StackOverflow is _definitely_ not good for asking three questions in one, even if they are related. The whole point of SO is hoping that an expert with the knowledge will come along and provide a perfect answer. If you merge 3 questions into one, you're requiring someone who's an expert in multiple areas, and even if you find one, he may not feel like writing that much. You'd really be better off on a more discussion-like forum, like the Kivy mailing lists.

Comment: so my question is now a single question : "So the question is why does kivy want the programmer to manually write those UI definitions like even hardcode the  positions and dimensions of UI widgets." @abarnert

Comment: I think you should still separate that out—again, manually-written declarative GUIs and statically-positioned widgets are almost completely orthogonal. I'll try to answer, but I suspect that, at least in this form, this question will get closed by others.

Comment: see the update i have made it focussed to that question.

Comment: " manually-written declarative GUIs and statically-positioned widgets are almost completely orthogonal" what it means? @abarnert

Comment: "Orthogonal" means "at right angles". They're independent of each other—you can have manually-written GUIs with statically-positioned widgets, manually-written GUIs with relatively-positioned widgets, GUI-designed GUIs with statically-positioned widgets, and GUI-designed GUIs with relatively-positioned widgets.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking why Kivy wasn't designed around a GUI interface builder:

In their [design philosophy doc](http://kivy.org/docs/philosophy.html#focused), they hint at the reason:

> Kivy is focused. You can write a simple application with a few lines of code. Kivy programs are created using the Python programming language, which is incredibly versatile and powerful, yet easy to use. In addition, we created our own description language, the Kivy Language, for creating sophisticated user interfaces. This language allows you to set up, connect and arrange your application elements quickly. We feel that allowing you to focus on the essence of your application is more important than forcing you to fiddle with compiler settings. We took that burden off your shoulders.

This implies pretty strongly that they believe that the way to make GUI applications less cumbersome *is* a text-driven declarative design like the `kv` language, not a WYSIWYG interface builder. So, that's why they did things this way.

But why would they think that? Well, here things get subjective.

You obviously don't agree with them. Apple doesn't either. Maybe Microsoft doesn't. But it's certainly the trend everyone else is following. People have moved from using graphical HTML designers to using a combination of declarative and procedural design directly in HTML and JS code. Macromedia created Flex to allow people to create Flash apps without having to use Flash Designer. The various cross-platform GUI frameworks (Gtk+, wx, Tk, JUCE, etc.) either don't have an interface builder, or have it as an optional "stepchild" tool; the only exception is Qt, which didn't get a tightly integrated designer until 4.0.

Take a look at how much work goes into Xcode and Visual Studio, and all the extra complex things Apple and Microsoft have to build to enable them (remember, both companies essentially took over and remade a programming language just to work with their interface builders, because the existing mainstream languages didn't fit). Kivy may be a commercially-funded project, but they don't have unlimited resources, and presumably they thought the effort they would have to spend on a doing something like Cocoa and Xcode could be better spent somewhere else.

---

For the side question on why they use static pixel-based layouts, like VB or wx, instead of relative layouts, like Cocoa or Qt… Well, first, it's *not* requiring that, it's giving you the *option*. There are advantages to both, but when you're trying to make it easier to design apps that look good on 320x480 screens at a time when everyone is noticing how badly HTML and other tools designed to be "scalable to any size" actually scaled to those sizes, I can see the advantages of pixel-perfect layout winning out. (Notice that HTML/CSS similarly gives you both options. And the earliest websites to make mobile pages took advantage of pixel-layout CSS, but they've gradually evolved as people worked out how to make "scalable" and "small" work together, and as mobile screens have become more variable.)

Comment: can you give examples to suggest that  "text-driven declarative design is the way to make GUI applications less cumbersome" as I find the opposite to be true by examples.

Comment: @stackit: All I can do is explain (or, really, guess) what Kivy was thinking. If you want the Kivy team to convince you that they made the _right_ decision, you're going to have to ask them. But really, this website is a pretty good example.

Comment: @abarnert. Your characterisation of Qt seems very odd. Qt deliberately [re-wrote Designer in version 4](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.0/qt4-designer.html) so that it became a completely independent component. But even so, there has never been anything like a "tightly integrated" designer in Qt. It has always been been possible to create GUIs without using Qt Designer, and that remains the case in Qt5. Even more to the point, Qt is now fully committed to [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeintroduction.html), which is a declarative UI definition language.

Comment: PS: I have never used kivy, but my first impression of the kv language is that it is *very* similar to QML in Qt.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Maybe "tightly integrated" isn't the right word. In 4.x, both QtDesigner and Qt itself were heavily reworked to work together better. As a result, QtDesigner provides access to every feature of Qt. That certainly doesn't mean you _have_ to use QtDesigner, just that you _can_ use it for everything, rather than having to constantly jump out of it or wrap or modify what it generates, which is what the OP wants, and KivyDesigner doesn't provide. My point is, none of the other competitors provide that either (except Xcode, VS, and Flash), and even Qt took a few years to get there.

Comment: @ekhumoro: As for kv, the Kivy team clearly took inspiration from the things they liked about different existing frameworks. QML is one of the best examples of a declarative UI definition language, so it's not surprising that they borrowed heavily from it, rather than from, say, Apple's NIB format, which is not exactly human-editable in a text editor.

Comment: A couple of clarifications: Kivy is not a commercially-funded project (except for occasional sponsorship from the PSF and participation in GSoC, to the extent they count), and kv does not demand static pixel-based layouts, that's a misunderstanding by the OP.

Comment: @inclement: Thanks; I'll edit the answer for the second part. For the first, I was referring to the "Funded" section of the Philosophy doc, which makes a bit point out of "Kivy is a community-influenced, professionally developed and commercially backed solution", to contrast it to some "vanishing student project".

Answer (score 2):

> like even hardcode the positions and dimensions of UI widgets.

You do not have to hardcode the positions and dimensions of UI widgets. Although you can do so, it's not usually the best idea, for the obvious reasons that you're probably thinking.

What you're probably missing is the role of layout classes, which impose some order on their child widgets. For instance, the BoxLayout stacks all its children in a horizontal or vertical row so that together they fill its area, with relative sizes determined by their size_hint properties. Using this and other layouts, you don't have to specify manual sizes and everything will automatically adapt to changes in the window size or the sizes of individual widgets.

As for why we use kv so much, abarnert's answer and discussion covers the philosophy and core reasons pretty well. That said, we aren't against the use of graphical tools, but none of the core devs are that invested in them. Kivy Designer is an early stage project to make such a thing, since it is a popular request, but development has been slow due to few contributions - plus I guess maintaining a gui builder is probably harder than parsing a simple language like kv. We do have a GSoC project on it this year, which hopefully will bring it to a more usable state that may attract more interest.

Comment: Why do I have a feeling that somewhere online, you could find a post from a TrollTech developer explaining the state of Qt 2.x and QtDesigner 1.0 in much the same terms? :)